# JQuery Searchable Dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a searchable list, created using JQuery Plugin from: http://plugins.jquery.com/searchit/

But i want some value to be selected by default when the list box shows up first time. Even though i have 'selected' mentioned in the option tag (Rockford in ex below). This part is not working.

Pls see here sample here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QuYJD/22/

```
$("select").searchit( { textFieldClass: 'searchbox' } );

    Type the search text:
    <br/>
    <select id="listBox1">
      <option>Robinhood</option>
      <option selected >Rockford</option>
      <option>Rome</option>
      <option>Ronda</option>
      <option>Rondon</option>
      <option>Rondonopolis</option>
      <option>Rongelap</option>
    </select>
```

Any idea? Or any other solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A kinda hacky way

Maybe you could do something like this after you init the plugin :

```
$(".searchbox").val($("#listBox1 :selected").val())
```

Because this plugin seems to be making you `select` into this:

```
<input type="textbox" id="__searchit2" class="searchbox">
<div id="__searchitWrapper2" style="display: none; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128); position: absolute;">
 <select id="listBox2" style="padding: 5px; margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;">
  <option>Robinhood</option>
  <option>Rockford</option>
  <option selected="">Rome</option>
  <option>Ronda</option>
  <option>Rondon</option>
  <option>Rondonopolis</option>
  <option>Rongelap</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

## Plugin change

I added another option to the plugin called `selected`. If you set it to `true`, then the text box will show your selected `option`. Just add this extra option :

```
$("select").searchit({
      textFieldClass: 'searchbox',
      selected: true
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/QuYJD/23/

Comment: hungerpain> Apparently this does not have support for keyboard up/down actions to move across the list items. Any idea?

Answer (score 29):

You can check the [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for jQuery. Its more user friendly and has vary nice UI.

It has the feature which you are looking for. Please go to the following link for more details

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Wow chosen is awesome

Comment: I'm using it but viewing it in mobile is not supported :(

Comment: It works with struts2 without any problem (unlike select2 plugin)