# How can Make a searchable DropDownList in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an asp.net mvc project and I have an action as below:

```
  public ActionResult RegisterCustomer()
    {
        ViewBagInput();
        ViewBag.ProvinceId = new SelectList(db.Province, "ID", "Title");
        if (User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name);
            Role.RoleTitle = user.Roles.RoleTitle;
            DataLayer.ViewModels.User.FullName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

this action returns the below view and sends the "ViewBag.ProvinceId" to this view(this viewbag sends the list of provinceID an ProvinceTitle to this view for showing in DropDownList for province that the Id of this dropdown is "ProvinceId"):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterCustomer", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions()
            {
                OnSuccess = "success",
                UpdateTargetId = "listUsers"

            },
                new { @Id = "theform" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.identificationNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.identificationNo) } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.identificationNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.FirstName) } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LastName) } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ProvinceId", null, "- choose a province- ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinceId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="divcities">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "- choose a city -", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)
                </div>

             }
```

And I have below jquery in this view :

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("#ProvinceId").change(function() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Customer/GetCities",
                data: { stateid: $("#ProvinceId").find(":selected").val() },
                type: "Post",
                dataType: "Html",
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#divcities").html(result);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

This jquery calls below action:

```
 public ActionResult GetCities(int stateid)
    {
        ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.City.Where(p => p.ProvinceID == stateid), "ID", "Title");
        return PartialView("CityPartialViewForCustomer");
    }
```

and this action returns below partialview:

```
    @model DataLayer.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel
<div class="control">
    @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, "- Choose a City ... -", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)
</div>
```

My first problem is that these place holders won't let me to type in this DropDownList and DropDownListFor and how can I solve this problem?
The second problem and most important problem is that the DropDownList and DropDownListFor are not searchable.How can I solve this?

Comment: Please do via jquery.
refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900527/jquery-searchable-dropdown-box

Comment: There is a very good plugin called `MagicSearch` that uses JQuery to achieve what you want. I have posted the answer here on how to use this plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111915/how-to-select-value-programmatically-with-magicsearch-jquery-plugin/54541236#54541236

Comment: Check this example: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Searchable-DropDownList-in-ASP-Net-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have added two ways for this you can choose any one of them** :

**1.** Check the below chosen plugin for jQuery. Its more useful, user friendly and has vary nice UI structure.

It has the many feature which you are looking for. Please go through the following link for more details

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

**2.** Other option is Select2, it's jQuery and it will provide you the reach look and feels:

[https://select2.org](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)

**Cheers** !!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Select2, it's jQuery and gives you search capability out of the box: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax